# Translate cURL JSON data to pycurl

Tags: curl, pycurl

I have this cURL command that returns a JSON file from some website:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
-d "{'item':'item-xyz',orientation:LANDSCAPE,choice:null}"
https://api.website.com/jsonApi/product/formatAndPrice
```

However, this Python code doesn't work and the website returns an error:

```py
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO

crl = pycurl.Curl()

file = open('out.json','wb')
crl.setopt(crl.WRITEDATA, file)

data = '{"item":"item-xyz","orientation":"LANDSCAPE","choice":null}'
buffer = BytesIO(data.encode('utf-8'))
crl.setopt(crl.READDATA, buffer)

crl.setopt(crl.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json'])
crl.setopt(crl.URL, "https://api.website.com/jsonApi/product/formatAndPrice")

crl.perform()
crl.close()
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: do crl.setopt(crl.VERBOSE, 1) and that should give you verbose output that may help you find the problem. The issue here is most likelythe ```crl.setopt(crl.READATA, buffer)```.

Comment: buffer is a python reserved keyword, so I'm not sure how you're code didn't error out previously. I don't think crl.READDATA is the current method to use. What I would use is crl.setopt(crl.POSTFIELDS, body) where body is a valid python dictionary. If you cahnged your data variable to a python dictionary aswell, it should work